# How to change the root of a website in .htaccess every year?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect

I want the root of a website change every year to a directory named by that year using an `.htaccess` file.

Simply I want this url `http://www.example.com/` redirect to this url `http://www.example.com/YYYY/` where the `YYYY` is an actual year (e.g. `2015`) using `.htaccess` file.

I have multiple questions:

**Which HTTP status code should I use?**
Should I use 301? But it changes every year! And I still want users to visit the `/` before being redirected!
Should I use 302? But it is not something temporary, the root url is being the same for one long year!
Should I use 307? But it is not 'Under Maintenance' page, it is the root of the web!

<s>**How could I make the url in my .htaccess rule be variable?**

Is there any .htaccess variable for year or should I change .htaccess file every year?</s> - I changed my mind, this wasn't what I want to do. I will rather change the year in `.htaccess` file when I release new year's website.

**Finally, could you help me to form the rule?**
Should I use `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` or `DirectoryIndex` or `mod_rewrite`?

P.S.: I would like to use relative paths in `.htaccess` file, if it is possible.

Comment: "temporarily, but permanently" is very confusing in English. Also, why do you want to do this? So users will still be able to reach previous years (e.g. example.com/2014/ )? I'm curious.

Comment: Yes, it is a website of a competition taking place every year. I want let users  to see the old year's webpages with propositions/winners/galleries...

Comment: I don't have a complete answer for you, but I suggest you use `RedirectMatch` instead of `mod_rewrite`, and I think the status code should be 307 because future requests to URLs without a year will continue to be valid.

Comment: I could be wrong about `RedirectMatch` if it doesn't allow the flexibility of defining the year dynamically - that would be a good enough reason to bring in `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: The 307 status code looks logical, thank you. The dynamically changing year is maybe OP condition. I could change it every year just when I want to release new year website (I just wanted to have a clean git commit history)

Comment: Finally I changed my mind, I want to switch years in May or June.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only redirecting the root URL (i.e. `/` and not `/entries`), you could use something as simple as this:

```
RedirectMatch 307 "^/$" /2015/
```

If you wanted to redirect any URL without a year, e.g. `/entries`, to URLs with years, e.g. `/2015/entries`, you would need a more complex rule to avoid looping -  `/2015/entries` redirecting to `/2015/2015/entries` etc.

Comment: It will do nicely. Thank you. `/enries` could be handled by `.htaccess` files inside folders, because universal solution would be too much complicated...